# Windows 10 shuts down/powers off randomly in sleep mode for no reason

Tags: windows, laptop, power, shutdown, kernel

My Windows 10 laptop (a Dell Inspiron 5491 2n1) shuts down randomly during sleep. It does not hibernate, nor perform a clean shutdown, it (seems to) simply power off. This also deletes all saved work.

There is no time that dictates when this event happens - I have had it happen when I just closed the lid for less than 30 seconds, but I have also kept my laptop in sleep mode overnight with no occurrence.

Not sure if this is related, but this issue has historically only happened when I had the lid closed.

I know that this is not a setting that I have forgotten to consider because I checked Event View logs and saw the following event whenever the computer shut down:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
   <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" />
      <EventID>41</EventID>
      <Version>8</Version>
      <Level>1</Level>
      <Task>63</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-06-02T07:02:09.7024410Z" />
      <EventRecordID>95636</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation />
      <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" />
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>DESKTOP-*******</Computer>
      <Security UserID="*-*-*-**" />
   </System>
   <EventData>
      <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data>
      <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data>
      <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data>
      <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data>
      <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data>
      <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data>
      <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data>
      <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data>
      <Data Name="Checkpoint">0</Data>
      <Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">true</Data>
      <Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">16</Data>
      <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">0</Data>
      <Data Name="BugcheckInfoFromEFI">false</Data>
      <Data Name="CheckpointStatus">0</Data>
      <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceIdV2">0</Data>
      <Data Name="LongPowerButtonPressDetected">false</Data>
   </EventData>
</Event>
```

[This is a Kernal-Power event from process ID 41 and priority 'Critical' (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlZor.png)

I would really appreciate it if somebody would help me debug this event. It has lead to the loss of more than one document over the past few months. I have also searched online and found some traces of it happening to others but not anything substantial or any solutions. I'm happy to provide more debug information if that helps.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this happening while plugged-in or only when on battery?

Comment: There should be an indicator on the outside of your machine that it went into sleep mode when you closed the lid. There must be an indicator - see what it says when you close the lid. It is probably failing to suspend sometimes. Update the Power Driver and BIOS.

Comment: @Mache it happens in both situations

Comment: @John My laptop model has no external indicator (such as a status light), there is only a *charging* light which indicates whether the cord is plugged in. I will look into power drivers for my model, thanks.

Comment: Contact Dell Support. The charging light may blink when disconnected from AC and the lid closed. Ask Dell how you are supposed to determine if the laptop went to sleep when you closed the lid.

Comment: Look at [Scenario 3 HERE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-event-id-41-restart).  You probably have a hardware error and [you aren't the only one](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-15-9500-Kernel-Power-error-unexpected-shut-down-during-sleep/td-p/7757127) even though this is a different Dell laptop.  How is the HEAT?  Also... look at the `Note:` at the bottom of the page, it might help you gather more information.